# Python - matplotlib.pyplot.imshow won't work in a if//while

Tags: python, image, loops, imshow

I'm trying to display an image (a N*P numpy array) in a while loop with imshow but it doesn't seem to work.

When I just use "plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')" with no indent it works perfectly.

However, when I try to use it from a while loop like

```
continue=True
while continue:
    plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')
    continue=input()
```

or

```
i=0
while i<10:
    plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')
    i+=1
```

the pyplot window just freeze and python crash (same problem with a if).

I don't understand why it does this, does anybody here knows? Thanks alot in advance :)

EDIT : I try to use it like this in my program

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as im

image=np.array(im.open("Blabla.jpg").convert('L')).astype(np.float32)

plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray') #This works -> ONLY when there is not a while after

keepGoin = True #But this doesn't
while keepGoin:
    plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')
    keepGoin=input()
```

EDIT 2 :

I made a mistake : it seems that imshow pauses when a while//if is used, even if the while loop is right after the imshow. And when the while loop ends, an image is finally displayed. Maybe using this kind of loop simply pauses the process ?

So I tried to use a secondary function aiming to display the image "out" of the while but it doesn't work either, the result is the same : the pyplot window freeze during the while loop, and the image is displayed right after the loop ends.

EDIT 3 :

So after some more tries, I am pretty sure the problem is not calling imshow from a while but the fact that the loop pauses the execution of pyplot, even if it is called BEFORE the loop (If I call imshow and then use a loop, the pyplot window freeze until the loop ends)

According to some new research I've made, plt.pause could help me but I've an error when I try this.

Comment: beware, ``continue`` is a python keyword, used to jump to the next loop iteration.

Comment: You may have to give more context for us to figure out why the second one breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However it's the same problem whatever the variable I use.

Comment: So if you add the `while` (and the indention) it fails, right?

Comment: @merlin2011: Well, in my program I try to use the first while loop to try different parameters to a gaussian filter, see the result and stop when it's satisfying.

But seeing it does not work, I tried this with a simple numpy array and using the simplified functions displayed up there and it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Mathias711 : Right. I try the simplest loop I thought and it fails.

Comment: @Gayral, Please update your question with the smallest fully working example that reproduces your problem. For example, show the code that was used to generate `image`, and ideally the import statements.

Comment: Dose **This works** mean the image windows is created on your screen? or there is not an error?

Comment: @mskimm: Yes : When it says This works, everything is fine, I can see my image in the new window.

But using the while, the window first pop, but then nothing happens, it freeze and I have to relaunch a python console.

Comment: please try to add `plt.ion()` in the front of `plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')`

Comment: @mskimm: I try to put it before the while but it doesn't help.

Comment: Nope, I mean before the first `plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')`

Comment: @mskimm : I tried this also but it has the same effet. Like I say in my EDIT2, it seems that using a while simply pauses pyplot, even when I want to display my image before the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some observations which might help you debug. The code and statements below only apply to `Python 2.x`.

Using the code below, you would have to type the word `True` or `False` on the console from which you started the program, for it to not crash after the first showing, because `input()` expects some sort of input and throws `EOF` if you do not give it anything.

```
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as im

image=np.array(im.open("Blabla.jpg").convert('L')).astype(np.float32)

plt.ion()
plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')

keepGoin = True #But this doesn't
while keepGoin:
    plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')
    keepGoin=input()
```

If you change it to `raw_input`, it is more forgiving in terms of not crashing with `EOF` but will still terminate unless you give it some input. However, changing the loop to be independent of the input paused it for me until I pushed `Enter` on the terminal.

```
while True:
    plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')
    raw_input()
```

Comment: That assumes Python 2.X. If it's Python 3 then ``input == raw_input``

Comment: @aruisdante, Very true. I am merely sharing observations though, which I hope will help the OP. They were just too large to fit in a comment.

Comment: Thanks, it'll be useful for the final UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Spider the easier way is configure to show the image in console because in the console the image not freeze.
To configure the spider to show the image on console:
preferences -> python console -> graphics -> output graphic -> here: choice inline instead of automatic

Comment: A screenshot to show the flow or final image would be great.